# Как в Angular 1.5 снаружи вызвать метод внутри component?

Tags: angularjs

Допустим есть контроллер MyController, в темплейте которого используется компонент someComponent. В someComponent есть метод myMethod. Как его вызвать из MyController`а?

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl as ctrl">
  <div ng-click="onClick()">click me</div>
  <my-component></my-component>  
</div> 

angular
  .module('app',[])
  .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.onClick = function () {}; 
  })
  .component('myComponent', {
    template: '<div ng-if="isParentPressed">Parent button pressed</div>',
    bindings: {},
    require: {},
    controller: function () {
      var $ctrl = this;
      $ctrl.$onInit = function () {
        $ctrl.isParentPressed = false;
      }; 

      $ctrl.onParentClick = function () {
        $ctrl.isParentPressed = true;
      }
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dennila2/x0tngvab/2/
Нужно, что бы по нажатию "onClick" запускался $ctrl.onParentClick() внутри компонента.

Comment: нужно добавить [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что пришло на ум:

1. Через $rootScope.$broadcast передать событие. Но как-то не хочется шуметь на все приложение.
2. Воспользоваться this.$onChanges(). Но от срабатывает только не конечных переменных. Если изменится объект - он не сработает.
3. Передать в родительский контроллер функцию. Но уж больно это замысловато. Мне кажется, что есть какой-то стандартный способ это сделать. http://jsfiddle.net/dennila2/x0tngvab/3/ .

   ```
   angular
     .module('app', [])
     .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
       $scope.onClick = function() {
         if (remote) remote.remoteFunc();
       };
       var remote;
       $scope.setRemote = function(remoteObj) {
         remote = remoteObj;
       };
     })
     .component('myComponent', {
       template: '<div ng-if="$ctrl.isParentPressed">Parent button pressed {{$ctrl.count}} times</div>',
       bindings: {
         remoteReady: '&'
       },
       controller: function() {
         var $ctrl = this;
         $ctrl.count = 0;
         $ctrl.isParentPressed = false;
         var remote = {
       remoteFunc: function () {
             $ctrl.isParentPressed = true;
             $ctrl.count++;
           }
         }
         $ctrl.remoteReady({remote: remote});
       }
     });
   ```

Comment: событие не обязательно слать из `$rootScope`, передача функции не такая уж и замысловата и часто используется для выполнения функции в родительском скопе. Так как компоненты это те же самые директивы, то кроме событий и параметров с внешним контроллером их ничего не связывает. Но, вместо внешнего контроллера можно сделать еще один компонент и применить [Intercomponent Communication](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#intercomponent-communication)

Answer (score 1):

```js
app.component('parentComponent', {
  ...
  controller: function(){
    this.foo = function(){...}
  },
  ...
})
app.component('childComponent', {
  ...
  require: {parent: "^parentComponent"},
  controller: function(){
    parent.foo()
  },
  ...
})
```